# Wired Wireless repeater

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router

I am trying to kill some dead spots in my home network when I discovered that my home has a convenient feature of ethernet threading from my office to the other side of my house. In my office I have a router and I would like to extend my network by connecting a repeater in the other side of my house, essentially a wifi repeater that uses a wired connection. Thank You.

Comment: *"ethernet threading from my office"* -- Do you mean some Ethernet cabling?  Try attaching a *wireless access point* to the other end of the cable.  But a wireless router (don't use the WAN port, disable DHCP and assign the LAN side an unused static IP address) are easier to find everywhere and will probably be less expensive.

Comment: Do they both need to hold the same SSID or would a wireless AP handle this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just setup both APs to provide the same SSIDs with the same encryption options, and passwords.  Put them on different wireless channels.

They should both have IP addresses on the same internal network.  DHCP should only be enabled on one AP.

Comment: And, last but not least, if you use a router, make sure to disable its DHCP server and connect it to the other one using its LAN port.

Comment: So I set it up as instructed but I am having a small problem. If I connect to wifi in the office I see wifi if I walk to the other side of the house, but if I walk back to the office the wifi doesn't switch and is left with a crappy signal. Any ideas on whats going on?

Comment: It's as if it connects to the office and successfully "catches" the other side of the house's wifi but fails to re-"catch" the office's wifi.

Comment: Ah, well if you where running 'enterprise' hardware I would suggest you lower the power on both APs, and adjust the AP settings so that the link to a wireless client gets dropped if they try to shift down to a slower speed.  There is a remote chance your hardware supports this.  Go in, and see if you have any options to refuse connections unless a client connects at a particular bandwidth.

Comment: @scipi0 Some devices have a "roaming aggressiveness" setting. Turn it up. (What device is it?)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I am using a NetGear N300 for my office and a netgear rangemax wpn824 in the other side of the house

Comment: Nevermind I fixed it.